# Redux avoid stale data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to implement, let's say Twitter. I'm doing something like

```
initialState = {
  tweets: {id => tweet}
}
```

then, a user goes to his timeline, now the action fetchTweets fetches all his tweets. However, then he can post a tweet, tweet T. But if I don't manually insert the posted T into state.tweets, he will not see this tweet in his timeline.

So here comes the question, when a user did some actions on his page, is that a good point to refresh the data? How does redux avoid data stale in this kind of case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Redux manages your state for you. It tells anyone who wants to hear about any changes in the state, such as React-Redux.

It does not do anything to help you with getting data, such as tweets. Nor does it help you decide when to get this data.

You'll have to decide for yourself when to do this and you can use `setTimeout` or anything else you feel like.

It's probably best if you manually insert the tweet into the state rather than refetch when you post. It's so much more responsive.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a paradigm shift when using Redux, but you don't want any functions to be your state. So, that initial state should actually just be either `null` or an empty object (depending on the design of the components that receive those props). But to answer your question a bit more directly, if you want to make sure that data stays "fresh" you need to make it happen. There is no magic in Redux, which is a GOOD THING.

However, if you design your code properly, the user shouldn't experience something resembling a full page refresh. At a high level, here is how I might design what you are describing.

Write actions for requesting and receiving tweets, i.e.:

```
export function requestTweets() => {
    return {
        type: REQUEST_TWEETS
    }  
}
export function receiveTweets(tweets) => {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_TWEETS,
        payload: tweets
    }  
}
```

Then wrap that in a "public" function that can be reused wherever:

```
export const fetchTweets = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(requestTweets())
        //network code here is pseudocode
        fetch('https://tweeter/api/v1/tweets')
        .then(data => dispatch(receiveTweets(data))
        .catch(err => displayErrorMsg(err))
    }
}
```

Then in your action handlers just reduce the tweets into the next state.

Now with fetchTweets, you can call that on the first load, after posting or on an interval. The nice thing is React will handle the diffing well for you and not re-render the entire page. It's just up to you to design it well so the user notices when and where new tweets come in.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Which middleware is this?